# Ember.js - Limit models in the store?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to limit the amount of models that exist in the Ember Data store? The use case for this is a chat app. It cannot be slowly eating away at the browser's memory as more and more `Message` models fill up. Preferably the oldest model would delete itself if there are more than 100 in store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can watch all the records of a type in the store, and delete them whenever there are more than you want.  This could really live on any controller/route...

```
App.MessagesRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  allMessages: function(){
    return this.store.all('message');
  }.property(),
  messageCount: Em.computed.alias('allMessages.length'),
  watchSize: function(){
    var cnt = this.get('messageCount'),
        messages;
    if(cnt>100){
       messages = this.get('allMessages').sortBy('messageDate').toArray().slice(100);
       messages.forEach(function(message){
         message.deleteRecord();
       });
    }
  }.observes('messageCount')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kingpin2k's answer, instead of `message.deleteRecord()` I would use `message.unloadRecord()` which would have almost the same effect locally (client side), but without any risk that the record be deleted from the server (this could happen with `deleteRecord` e.g. if a there were a call to `message.save()` afterwards, which could happen "accidentally" in complex apps).

In other words, `deleteRecord` should be used when the client wants to delete the record server side.